# Okay to cast java tangent to a double

Tags: java, android, math

I'm trying to adjust for the angle of something in my code and using the tangent function like so:

```
(float) StrictMath.tan(X_THETA *Math.PI/180);
```

I was surprised to see that there wasn't a variant of tan that took a float, so I cast it instead. I get that I'll lose some precision here but is that the only downside? Am I missing something and there's another way to calculate tangent of a float. Surprisingly googling Android Java tangent of float didn't bring me much.

Thank you

Comment: Aside: `Math.toRadians` is perhaps better than `Math.PI/180`.

Comment: Why must you cast?  What is your reason for not using the double that tangent provides?  I see no good reason to do so.

Comment: @duffymo because rest of my functions and libraries require float values...

Comment: You’re using the wrong libraries

Comment: @duffmo using opencv where they work in floating point